# Taiwan TAC With An Unused Japanese Visa

Tags: india, japan, taiwan

I'm an Indian and I intend to visit Japan after visiting Taiwan.

I have an unused Japan Visa which is valid till October. Can that be used to get an entry in Taiwan along with a TAC or do I first need to get my Japanese visa stamped before they'd allow me to enter Taiwan?

Thanks

Edit: TAC stands for Travel Authorisation Certificate

Comment: @David That only seems to cover Pakistani citizens, so doesn't apply.

Comment: @David Duplicate does **not** mean "If you read an answer in the linked question and, on the off chance, happen to follow a link in that answer, you'll find the answer to your question."

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Taiwan's Bureau of Consular Affairs maintains [a webpage](https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-159-249-4162c-2.html) where visa information for the Republic of China (R.O.C., or Taiwan) is presented in English. That page contains the following, which sets requirements for an Indian citizen (as well as citizens of the other 16 countries listed, which names I've omitted from this Answer) to obtain a visa to enter Taiwan.

"Nationals from the following countries applying for visitor visas to the R.O.C. must fulfill the procedure of this section：

...

"India (Identify Certificate)

...

"Nationals of the designated countries may apply for the R.O.C. visitor visas for  the following purposes：

- Invited by the Republic of China (R.O.C.) government agencies on
  official missions
- Participating in international meetings or activities for the
  purposes of  religious, athletic, or cultural exchange, which are
  held by the organizations set up in the R.O.C.
- Visiting dependents with legal residence status in the R.O.C.,
  including spouse, family members of  lineal relationship, or
  siblings.
- Conducting economic or commercial businesses.（including accompanied
  spouse and children...
- Crew members intending to come to the R.O.C. to report for duty.
- Medical treatment."

Unless your planned trip to Taiwan fits within one of these six categories, you will not quaify for a visa.